# adding pages in live asp.net site dynamically without redeploying or recompiling?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0

Is there some way to add .aspx pages in live asp.net site without need to recompile or redeploy ? Please guide me.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

I do not exactly understand what do you mean by "no recompile or redeploy", but:

If you use Asp.Net web site(and not web application) you can just copy aspx file with it's cs file to the web site directory and it will work.

Comment: Yes, but there's no way to add code without recompiling (which happens when the pool is recycled)

Comment: No it won't, try it. In web site each page is compiled to different assembly and each of those assemblies just loaded to app-pool

Comment: thanks buddies,

I meant to added by admin, like there admin can add new page dynamiclly.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can simply upload aspx and cs page to the given location. If you publish your site you can upload only page related dll and aspx page.